# Javascript - Switching array name in foreach function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

trying to make this as simple to understand as possible...

I have a JS function that essentially picks which array (a list) a person has selected and then passes it to another function to then print that array out. The problem is I can't figure out how to use the array name that I have passed take a look:

Arrays:

```
var allLists =['list1', 'list2'];
var list1 = ['orange', 'pear', 'apple'];
var list2 = ['car', 'plane', 'bike'];
```

Function to loop through the lists:

```
function printAllLists() {
    lists.forEach(function(entry) {
        count++;
        document.write("<h2> List Number " + count + "</h2>");
        printList(entry);

    });
}
```

Function to output each list contents to a table

```
function printList(listname) {
    document.write("<table>");
    document.write("List Name Is: " + listname);

    listname.forEach(function(entry) {  //HERE IS THE PROBLEM   
        document.write("<tr><td>");
        document.write(entry);
        document.write("</td></tr>");   
    });
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

The problem I have is the line below literally uses "listname" rather than what has been passed as list name which should be either "list1" or "list 2"

```
listname.forEach(function(entry) {
```

So it just fails with this error. How can I get it to swap the name of the array instead. Sorry if its not really clear what I'm trying to say I'm not sure how to exactly word this (which is probably why google isn't helping.)

```
Uncaught TypeError: listname.forEach is not a function
```

**JSFiddle** 
Link to JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/38x5nw62/
Thanks

Comment: `window[listName].forEach` is it is at the global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
var list1 = ['car', 'plane', 'bike'];
var list2 = ['car', 'plane', 'bike'];
var allLists = [list1, list2];
```

Working Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/38x5nw62/1/

You where using `var allLists = ['list1', 'list2'];` wich does only contain strings `'list1'` and `'list2'`, NOT the variables/arrays named smiliarly to the strings.

Comment: Thanks @CodeiSir I knew It would be something simple I was missing!